# How do I use % in python 3

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have a python code written in 2.7 and i would have to upgrade it to python 3 how do i go about the syntax difference raw_input and at %

```
n=[]

print('Welcome to Rock-Paper-Scissors')

gamenum = int(input("How many games of Rock-Paper-Scissors you want to play?"))
while  (gamenum % 2 == 0):
        gamenum = int(input("Please enter an odd number of games:"))
else:
        n.insert(0, range (1,gamenum+1))


computer = ''
for i in range(gamenum):
  player = raw_input('Game %d\nYou can pick\n' % (i + 1))
  if player == computer:
        print("Tie!")
  elif (player == "R"):
        computer = 'Paper'# == "Paper"
        print('The computer picked') , computer, ('You lose.')
  elif (player == "P"):
        computer = 'Scissors'# == "Scissors"
        print('The computer picked') , computer, ('You lose.')
  elif (player == "S"):
        computer = 'Rock'# == "Rock"
        print('The computer picked') , computer, ('You lose.')
```

Comment: There is nothing called `row_input`. Perhaps you just wanted `input`?

Comment: I am sorry I fixed it, I added the row_input instead of input

Comment: @Mohamed, you have misunderstood. `row_input` does _not_ exist.

Comment: What he is saying is, change `player = row_input('Game %d\nYou can pick\n' % (i + 1))` to `player = input('Game %d\nYou can pick\n' % (i + 1))` since `row_input` does not exist.

Comment: raw_input my bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the `str.format()` [functionality](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/string.html) in python 3.
Application-wise the jist is that `'%d is a number' % 5` is <strike>replaced</strike> complemented by `'{} is a number'.format(5)`, but there is actually much more. You can supply keyword arguments, formatting conditions and even make method calls with the `{}` syntax.

So

```
'Game %d\nYou can pick\n' % (i + 1))
```

Would become anything between

```
'Game {}\nYou can pick\n'.format(i + 1)
```

and

```
'Game {number:0^3d}\nYou can pick\n'.format(number=i + 1)
```

Comment: It's never "replaced", it's just two ways of doing it. Some people prefer using formatting because it looks neater, while both ways can do almost exactly the same things

Comment: Fair point, I edited the answer. TIL, I liked the new formatting so much that I never came around to trying whether %-formatting still existed ;)

Comment: formate worked well, but still raw_input still an issue

Comment: I believe `raw_input` has been replaced by [`input`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#input).